# How do we make .htpasswd to prompt on each visit?

Tags: .htaccess, each, prompt, .htpasswd

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile mywebsite/accounts/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

This is the current .htaccess file and have a .htpasswd file where we have user and password.

We would like to prompt htpasswd on each visit, what changes should I make to get this?

Answer (score 0):

> How do we make .htpasswd to prompt on each visit?

Not at all. The prompt is not generated by the password file on your server, but by the browser requesting that page. It stores the credentials, so there's nothing the server can do about that.

Comment: So, is there any possible way to call htaccess file from the client?